# Scrapy: missing xpath item causes wrong data to be written to my pipeline

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, export-to-csv

This is a newbie question (new to Scrapy and first question on Stackoverflow):

I currently have a spider to crawl the following Amazon page (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Televisions-TVs-LED-LCD-Plasma/b/ref=sn_gfs_co_auto_560864_1?ie=UTF8&node=560864).

I am trying to scrape the title of the TV and main (listed) price. I can successfully parse the TV name. However on some of the Amazon TVs listed they don't all have the same Xpath elements; some have a main (listed) price, some have a "as New" price and some also have a "as Used" price.

My issue is that when a TV does not have a main (listed) price my CSV output does not record a NULL for that item but instead takes the next XPATH item which does have a main price.

**Is there a way to check whether an item exists in the XPATH content and if not to get the spider or the pipeline to record a NULL or ""?**

My main spider code is:

```
class AmazonSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.co.uk"]
    start_urls = [
     "http://www.amazon.co.uk/Televisions-TVs-LED-LCD-Plasma  /b/ref=sn_gfs_co_auto_560864_1?ie=UTF8&node=560864"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    title = sel.xpath('.//*[starts-with(@id,"result_")]/h3/a/span/text()').extract()
    price = sel.xpath('.//*[starts-with(@id,"result_")]/ul/li[1]/div/a/span/text()').extract()

    items = []
    for title,price in zip(title,price):
        item = AmazonItem()
        item ["title"] = title.strip()
        item ["price"] = price.strip()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

My pipeline is:

```
class AmazonPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

My items file is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
```

I am outputing to CSV as follows:
    scrapy crawl amazon -o output.csv -t csv

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can take the xpath relatively so that this won't happen again
Look at the code below, this might help

```
 def parse(self, response):
    selector_object = response.xpath('//div[starts-with(@id,"result_")]')
    for select in selector_object:
        title = select.xpath('./h3/a/span/text()').extract()
        title = title[0].strip() if title else 'N/A'
        price = select.xpath('/ul/li[1]/div/a/span/text()').extract()
        price = price[0].strip() if price else 'N/A'
        item = AmazonItem(
              title=title,
              price=price
               )
        yield item
```

Comment: Thanks Jithin. Appreciate your input. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem I had which was failing to pick up a missing item.  It did inspire an alternative approach which did solve my problem. I'll post my solution below as a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

I extended Jithin's approach by a couple of if else statements which helped solve my problem:

```
def parse(self, response):
    selector_object = response.xpath('//div[starts-with(@id,"result_")]')
    for select in selector_object:
        new_price=select.xpath('./ul/li[1]/a/span[1]/text()').extract()
        title = select.xpath('./h3/a/span/text()').extract()
        title = title[0].strip() if title else 'N/A'
        price = select.xpath('./ul/li[1]/div/a/span/text()').extract()
        if price:
            price = price[0].strip() 
        elif new_price:
            price = new_price[0].strip()

        item = AmazonItem(
            title=title,
            price=price
            )
        yield item
```